# MySQL select latest distinct records from user where with latest date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, select

I have a table called "lift":

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   ID   |   USERNAME   |  lift_ID    |    DATE    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   1    |     user1    |      0      | 2013-06-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   2    |     user1    |      0      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   3    |     user1    |      1      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   4    |     user2    |      0      | 2013-06-04 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   5    |     user2    |      1      | 2013-06-04 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   6    |     user2    |      1      | 2013-06-05 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   7    |     user1    |      2      | 2013-06-03 |
```

I want to select all distinct `lift_id`'s from a certain user where the date is the latest of that `lift_id` of that user.

If I would do that for user1 I would get:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   2    |     user1    |      0      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   3    |     user1    |      1      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   7    |     user1    |      2      | 2013-06-03 |
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM lift l1 
 WHERE date` = (
       SELECT MAX(date)
         FROM lift 
        WHERE l1.lift_id = lift.lift_id)
          AND username = 'user1'
        ORDER BY lift_id ASC
       )
 ;
```

That select's all distinct lifts on the max date but doesn't take account of the different users which is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is close.  You need an additional correlation clause in the subquery:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM lift l
WHERE l.date = (select max(l2.date)
                from lift l2
                 where l2.lift_id = l.lift_id and
                      l2.username = l.username
               ) and
      l.username = 'user1'
ORDER BY l.lift_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT t.* FROM lift t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM lift s
                 WHERE s.lift_id = t.lift_id 
                   AND s.username = t.username
                   AND s.date > t.date)
```